# Turnkey Linux Net-SNMP

Tags: linux, php, turnkey-linux

Trying

> "apt-get install net-snmp"

command to use SNMP commands. but the server says "Unable to locate package net-snmp"

This is where I'm told I require Net-SNMP; http://php.net/manual/en/snmp.requirements.php

but it looks like net-snmp isn't available from the repositories of this installation

This is for a Turnkey Linux web server.

I've tried

> "apt-get install php5-snmp"

but I am still getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function snmpget()
```

Comment: Oops, just realised that it isn't a duplicate... sorry...! Just deleted my answer.

Comment: TBH, I'm not 100% sure of your use case, but it seems that there is also a `snmp` package: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/snmp - perhaps that needs to be installed as well? Also I noticed that it comes from a source package called net-snmp https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/net-snmp Also it may pay to check that the function that you are trying to use is supported by php5.6 (whats in Debian Jessie/TKLv14.x).